# Angular8 Reactive Form Validators Together With Async Validator

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I have an error when i try to show an error in the DOM when validating validators & async validators

My error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of null at
>   Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

In component html:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">email</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                id="email"
                formControlName="email"
                class="form-control">
            <div *ngIf="!signupForm.get('userData.email').valid && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched ">
              <span class="help-block"
                *ngIf="signupForm.get('userData.email').errors['required'] && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched">Email
                is required
              </span>
              <span class="help-block"
                *ngIf="signupForm.get('userData.email').errors['email'] && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched">Email
                is not valid
              </span>
            </div>
```

In component.ts :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'userData': new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.forbiddenNames.bind(this)]),
        'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails),
      }),
      'gender': new FormControl('male'),
      'hobbies': new FormArray([])
    });
  }
```

Note: when i remove the async validator, (this.forbiddenEmails) from the form control async validator, it works:

```
'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmails)
```

(Works when i have only validators without async validators 
i get no error, but i want to show the error for the async validator as well .)

Comment: See the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396057/cannot-read-property-required-of-null

Comment: I am using Reactive Form - not Template Driven Form
So this is not going to work....
I managed to avoid that error by using 'hasError('errorName')

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using "hasError('errorName')":

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">email</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                id="email"
                formControlName="email"
                class="form-control">
            <div *ngIf="!signupForm.get('userData.email').valid && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched ">
              <span class="help-block"
                *ngIf="signupForm.get('userData.email').hasError('required') && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched">Email
                is required
              </span>
              <span class="help-block"
                *ngIf="signupForm.get('userData.email').hasError['email'] && signupForm.get('userData.email').touched">Email
                is not valid
              </span>
```

Email
                    is not valid